# Making wget a bash.sh

Tags: bash, wget, download

Need help turning this wget string in to a bash script because I use it frequently. 
`wget -nd -H -r -l 1 -A jpg,jpeg,bmp,gif,png,mp4,webm -e robots=off`

So far I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -nd -H -r -l 1 -A jpg,jpeg,bmp,gif,png,mp4,webm -e robots=off "${URL}"
```

When I do

```
myscript.sh http://example.com/where/thefilesare
```

I get

```
http://: Invalid host name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -nd -H -r -l 1 -A jpg,jpeg,bmp,gif,png,mp4,webm -e robots=off $1
```

The reason that your script doesn't work is because the script doesn't know where to get `URL` from. `$1` simply refers to the first argument of the script. If this script gets much more complicated, I'd recommend reading up on how to parse command line arguments in bash. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash) seems like a good place to start.

Also, you could put this command as an alias in your shell `rc` file, or your shell profile file, which has various advantages including being able to move it round easily as part of a dotfiles git repository.

Comment: Can you just spoon feed this to me? I reviewed the link and I'm still not getting it, not sure why.

Comment: Nevermind I should have read your comment from the beginning it works. Thanks mate.